# "Было бы для кого". Запятая перед "для" нужна ли?

Tags: пунктуация

> Наряды, прически, выезды ― все это делало Катю еще более жалкой в их
> глазах и не заслуживающей снисхождения. **Было бы для кого**
> разрываться!

О. А. Шапир. Авдотьины дочки (1898)

Нужна ли запятая перед "для"? У автора запятой - нет. Почему?

Текст, из которого взята цитата, такой:

"«Ну!.. распустилась вся, словно мед!» ― думала не раз с негодованием Ариша, глядя на то, как барышня не знает уж чем и угодить желанному гостю. Наряды, прически, выезды ― все это делало Катю еще более жалкой в их глазах и не заслуживающей снисхождения. **Было бы для кого** разрываться! Что касается жениха, то Авдотьины дочки давно разобрали его по косточкам, живого места не осталось. Перед праздниками Катерина Николаевна, после мучительных колебаний, решилась поехать на бал медицинских студентов. Уже несколько лет, как Катя перестала выезжать на публичные балы; кавалеров знакомых нет, а за скуку каждый раз еще поплатишься головной болью."

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146 — пункт 7.

Comment: Было бы для кого разрываться! А как разобрать это предложение по составу? Это сказуемое в 5 слов? И у Розенталя я не нашла "было бы для кого/чего".

Comment: Да, при грамматическом разборе неплохо было бы указать основу, если разбор предложения действительно нужен. В таких случаях есть основная база и дополнительные распространители, которые могут меняться. С точки зрения грамматики конструкция интересная.

Comment: Я там (в вопросе) добавила текста побольше...

Comment: Меня заодно заинтересовало, почему нет запятой перед 'уж'. *"...барышня не знает уж чем и угодить желанному гостю"* — у Достоевского, к примеру, запятая в таком случае имеется: *"Не знаю уж, чем и угодить тебе…"* ('Братья Карамазовы").

Answer (score 1):

1. Как уже говорилось, по правилу Розенталя запятая в таких предложениях **не ставится:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146  § 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения

Пункт 7. Внутри выражений типа есть чем заняться, есть над чем поработать, было о чём подумать, найду куда обратиться, не нахожу что сказать, состоящих из глагола быть, или найти (найтись), или остаться и вопросительно-относительного местоимения либо наречия (кто, что, где, куда, когда и т. д.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола, запятая не ставится.

2. Остается разобрать **грамматику этого предложения**, чтобы понять обоснованность такого решения.

***Было бы для кого разрываться!*** Предложение имеет иронический оттенок. Смысл его такой: *Не для кого было разрываться*. По форме оба предложения относятся к безлично-инфинитивным.

3. **Безлично-инфинитивные** предложения сочетают в себе свойства безличных и инфинитивных предложений. В качестве обязательных структурных элементов они включают  **инфинитив, местоимение и связку в безличной форме** (в настоящем времени — нулевую). Безлично-инфинитивные предложения имеют **три основные формы:**

1. отрицательную: Нечего читать; Не о чем говорить; Незачем туда ехать; Не к кому обратиться;
2. утвердительную: Есть что читать; Есть о чем поговорить; Есть зачем ехать; Есть к кому обратиться;
3. вопросительную: Что нам было читать?; К кому нам было обратиться?

4. ***Было бы для кого стараться!*** (Не для  кого было стараться.)

В состав сказуемого входит связка в нужной форме (было бы) и инфинитив, но дополнение ***для кого*** является обязательным структурным элементом, хотя в состав сказуемого оно не входит. Разумеется, ни о какой запятой здесь вообще не может быть речи.

Аналогично в безличных предложениях со словом ***нет*** в качестве сказуемого также  обязательно присутствует **дополнение** (нет времени, не было времени).